# i can't use the likes graph api with the facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

i want to add a likes in my facebook page, but failed, the codes is:

```
Bundle par = new Bundle();  
par.putString("access_token", ACCESS_TOKEN); 
par.putString("format", "json");
facebook.request("72447883975/likes", par, "POST");
```

the response is "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call".
Does anyone knows which permission need for this call? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need "publish_stream" to post comments/news while logging the user to the facebook like as below.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + <your app is>  + 
                "&redirect_uri=" +<redirect uri>
                "/connect" +
                "/login_success.html/" +
                "&scope=offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream" +
                "&display=touch&type=user_agent"
```

Answer (score 0):

last time i checked, it was not possible to like certain objects (pages) via the API. Maybe that has changed, but you might need to use the opengraph API for this.